# Calling JDBC to impala/hive from within a spark job and creating a table

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-spark, impala

I am trying to write a spark job in scala that would open a jdbc connection with Impala and let me create a table and perform other operations.

How do I do this?  Any example would be of great help. 
Thank you!

Comment: Hi , did you achieved this ? if so can you please share

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
val JDBCDriver = "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver"
val ConnectionURL = "jdbc:impala://url.server.net:21050/default;auth=noSasl"

Class.forName(JDBCDriver).newInstance
val con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL)
val stmt = con.createStatement()
val rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)

val resultSetList = Iterator.continually((rs.next(), rs)).takeWhile(_._1).map(r => {
    getRowFromResultSet(r._2) // (ResultSet) => (spark.sql.Row)
}).toList

sc.parallelize(resultSetList)
```

Comment: awesome thanks for the great example! Do you have any info on how this would look in Python?

Comment: what a lot of folks are looking for