# Converting JDBC ResultSet to Spark RDD/DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, rdd, resultset

I was trying to convert JDBC ResultSet to Spark RDD and was looking for an efficient way to do that using parallelism feature of Spark.

Below is what i have implemented as per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32073423/6064131

```
val rs:ResultSet = stmt .getResultSet
val colCount = rs.getMetaData.getColumnCount

def getRowFromResultSet(resultSet: ResultSet): String ={
  var i:Int = 1
  var rowStr=""
  while(i<=colCount){
    rowStr=rowStr+resultSet.getString(i)+delim
    i+=1
  }
  rowStr
}

val resultSetList = Iterator.continually((rs.next(), rs)).takeWhile(_._1).map(r => {
  getRowFromResultSet(r._2) // (ResultSet) => (spark.sql.Row)
}).toList

val x = sc.parallelize(resultSetList)
```

Now the main issue is it is taking more time and i understand all dataset is pulled through one needle eye.But is there any better way to achieve this?

Some might be wondering why i am not using inbuilt feature sqlContext.read.format to achieve this, the reason is Spark wraps a "SELECT * FROM ( )" around the query which is creating issue with complex queries.
Please refer the link for details [Issue with WITH clause with Cloudera JDBC Driver for Impala - Returning column name instead of actual Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593080/issue-with-with-clause-with-cloudera-jdbc-driver-for-impala-returning-column-n)

Comment: You didn't try Spark 2, I'm guessing?

Comment: @cricket_007 How Spark 2 will make any difference?

Comment: Significant improvement in the SparkSQL code. Just curious

Answer (score 0):

> But is there any better way to achieve this?

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. If you still experience the same issue with a recent Spark version (1.6 is **pretty old**) and JDBC driver (my guess it is the one to blame) just [`CREATE VIEW`](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_create_view.html) and use it for queries.

Also don't forget to file a bug report.